# how to change the text layout color to white and text to black using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I have this image.

[image: this]

I want to make all the colored headings to white and the text in it to black.

I try below to make the image full black and white.

```
img_grey = cv2.imread('img.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
thresh = 170
img_binary = cv2.threshold(img_grey, thresh, 250, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
cv2.imwrite('bw_img.jpg',img_binary)
```

Now those headings are black and text within those is white. But i want to make text black and heading layout white. So, can anyone helps me with that?

Comment: Replace `cv2.THRESH_BINARY` with `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV`.

Comment: It works for headings but it also makes whole image background black. I want to change only those pink headings.

Answer (score 1):

You may convert the image to HSV, apply threshold to find colored regions, and copy the result of `cv2.threshold` with `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV` only to the colored regions.

Main stages of the suggested solution:

- Convert from BGR to HSV color space, and get the saturation color channel.
  all black and white are zero, and colored pixels are above zero.
- Apply threshold to the saturation channel.
- Find contours on the binarized saturation channel.
- Draw the contours as white (255 values) on black background to form a mask.
- Apply morphological closing for closing some black gaps.
- Get only the area inside the mask from `img_binary_inv` (result of your code using `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV`).
- Copy masked `img_binary_inv` to `img_grey` only in pixels that mask is white.

---

Complete code sample:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img_bgr = cv2.imread('img.jpg')  # Read image as BGR

img_grey = cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # Convert from BGR to grayscale.

thresh = 170
img_binary_inv = cv2.threshold(img_grey, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]  # Apply threshold and invert black/white

# Convert from BGR to HSV color space.
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Get the saturation color channel - all black and white are zero, and colored pixels are above zero.
s = hsv[:, :, 1]

thresh = 100
s_binary = cv2.threshold(s, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]  # Apply threshold to the saturation channel.

# Find contours on s_binary
cnts = cv2.findContours(s_binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2]  # Use index [-2] to be compatible to OpenCV 3 and 4

# Draw the contours as white (255 values) on black background.
mask = np.zeros_like(s_binary)
cv2.drawContours(mask, cnts, -1, 255, -1)

# Apply morphological closing for closing some black gaps.
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, np.ones((3, 3)))

# Get only the area inside the mask from img_binary_inv
masked_binary_inv = cv2.bitwise_or(img_binary_inv, img_binary_inv, mask=mask)

# Copy masked_binary_inv to img_grey only in pixels that mask is white.
cv2.copyTo(masked_binary_inv, mask, img_grey)

cv2.imwrite('img_grey.png', img_grey)  # Save result (as PNG and not JPEG for better quality).

# Show images
cv2.imshow('img_bgr', img_bgr)
cv2.imshow('s_binary', s_binary)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('masked_binary_inv', masked_binary_inv)
cv2.imshow('img_grey', img_grey)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Result (`img_grey`):
[image]
The result doesn't look so good, due to the relatively low quality of the input image.

---

Intermediate results:

`s_binary`:
[image]

`mask`:
[image]

`masked_binary_inv`:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works really well but it also makes some headings complete white and some headings half part. So, how to deal with it?

Comment: **1.** Try to get a better quality image sample (at least in PNG lossless format, and not JPEG). **2.** The red text inside the yellow area is white, because the solution doesn't handle colored text inside colored regions. You may solve it using the information of the hue color channel of HSV (it looks complicated). The colored regions doesn't cover the text from all directions. You may improve it by dilating the `mask`. **3.** Lower your expectations from answers in Stack Overflow - the answers are just guidance, not perfect solutions that handles all the cases.